# Is MySQL Community server same as basic MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql

As I wanna learn SQL and MySQL

n since MySQL is said to be open source , so on MySQL site there is nothing as "MySQL Database" term written in it's downloads.

All i can see there is

MySQL Community Server,

MySQL Standard,

MySQL Enterprise,

etc..

So i was wondering, what to download since i m a new learner

Also Enterprise seems to have almost all basic n intermediate features n Work-Bench also.

MySQL Community server doesn't specifies what it includes in package.

So Please Advice ! Which one to go for to learn MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Only the **Community Server Edition** is [free](http://www.mysql.com/products/), so I think that pretty much restricts your choices unless you're willing to pay upwards of $2000/yr.